# Electrical symbols, what does a dot before a triangle mean?

Tags: diagram, symbol

Good day.

Trying to recreate a circuit, but I'm not sure what the dot BEFORE the triangle means. I know after it means invertor, does before just mean it's inverted BEFORE, instead of after? Rather confused, and not having luck searching.

Really appreciate the help.

[image: BCD-to-7 segment latch decoder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another way of drawing a logic inverter ("NOT").

The triangle-with-bubble is an inverter: logic high input yields logic low output, and vice versa. Usually the bubble is shown on the output, but in a mixed-logic system, the bubble can be shown on the input instead.

When the bubble is on the input instead of the output, that indicates that the input is an active-low input.

Comment: Thank you. Any insight as to why it's inverted 3 times at the inputs?

Comment: It seems the inverters are used as a buffer for the input signal.  It might be this was the easiest way to make it on the silicon.

Comment: Perhaps to increase the fan-out on the lower Not LE, and also used for the D inputs above to equalise transit time.

Answer (score 3):

It indicates an active-low input, active-low means you must apply 0V to make gate working.

[Here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_4.html) you can find good explanation

> The “bubble” (o) present at the end of the NOT gate symbol above
>   denotes a signal inversion (complementation) of the output signal. But
>   this bubble can also be present at the gates input to indicate an
>   active-LOW input. This inversion of the input signal is not restricted
>   to the NOT gate only but can be used on any digital circuit or gate as
>   shown with the operation of inversion being exactly the same whether
>   on the input or output terminal. The easiest way is to think of the
>   bubble as simply an inverter.

Comment: I've been on that site all night, not sure how I missed that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If someone's stumbled upon this question looking for a slightly different usage such as in this picture:
[image: Another example of circle order]

You might want to check this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/452460